# Mulithreaded communication in Tkinter without spawning unnecessary threads

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I have a Tkinter application within which an `update()` function is called every `x` ms in order to update the GUI.

`update()` looks something like this:

```
def update(self):
   # update some gui variables
   if self.point_iteration_done and not overall_point_done (and some other bools are true):
      self.do_point()

   self.after(x ms, self.update)
```

`do_point()` sets the variable `point_iteration_done` to `False` and then starts a thread for a function called `point_thread_handler()`.

```
def do_point(self):
   self.point_iteration_done = False
   point_thread = Thread(target=point_thread_handler, args=..., daemon=True).start()
```

`point_thread_handler(self)` calls the actual pointing function imported from another class (which may take several seconds to execute) and then once that's done, posts a virtual event: `self.event_generate(<<PointingThreadFinished>>")`

```
def point_thread_handler(self):
   # check some conditions, then
   self.PointClass.point(args=...)
   self.event_generate("<<PointingThreadFinished>>")
```

Then there is a line `self.bind("<<PointingThreadFinished>>", lambda event: self.on_pointing_complete())` in the constructor of the GUI class, and `on_pointing_complete()` sets the `point_iteration_done` to `True` and then reads the value of `overall_pointing_done` (which is set within the pointing class in another thread).

```
def on_pointing_complete(self):
   self.point_iteration_done = True
   if self.pointing.overall_pointing_done:
            self.is_overall_pointing_done = True
```

The problem I'm having is that on some occasions more than 1 extra thread spawns (sometimes up to 10 or more) when there should only be a maximum of 2 threads (one for Tkinter main loop and one for pointing).I know this because upon closing the GUI, I sometimes see:

```
Exception in thread Thread-10 (pointing_thread_handler):
File "C:\Users\...", line 400, in pointing_thread_handler
    self.event_generate("<<PointingThreadFinished>>")
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1914, in event_generate
    self.tk.call(args)
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
```

Is there a better way to gracefully handle creation and communication between threads to ensure extra, unnecessary threads never form?

More precisely for this case, a point thread should only be formed if the previous point thread is done.

Comment: Can you provide an [mre] (you can replace the long executing function with `time.sleep(3)`)? How and when are you spawning new threads? Also how are you confirming that you have 10 threads running at the same time?

Comment: @TheLizzard just updated the question above with more details. I know there are more than 2 threads due to an exception that occurs (see above)

Comment: `point_iteration_done` is a local variable inside `do_point()`, not the global one.

Comment: this is particularly poor way of writing a GUI, instead of creating animation frames that perform updates every Xms, try to use the async library. It'll make your life easier and the user experience much better.

Comment: The error that you are getting is just `tkinter` complaining because you called `.event_generate` from another thread. It's discouraged to call `tkinter` methods from threads other than the one where you create the `tk.Tk()`. It will complicate your program quite a bit but instead of `event_generate` you can set a boolean variable. And you can have a `.after` loop that check if the boolean variable is set instead of the `.bind`.

Comment: @OM222O I don't think `asinc` and `tkinter` play nicely. `tkinter` uses events and `after` scripts which are all called from inside the `mainloop`.

Comment: @TheLizzard to be completely honest I haven't used the package before, but I know a few people who have. `aiotkinter` seems to be the solution for making `asyncio` work nicely with tkinter, but again, haven't actually used it myself.

Comment: Closing the GUI does not close the secondary thread.  So you can expect to see an error message if the tkinter event loop closes before the secondary thread finishes.  You can hook the close event in tkinter and wait for the second thread to close; you can catch and suppress the specific RuntimeError in the second thread.  I don't know why you think you have ten threads but you _know_ you have two.  You need to shutdown the second one gracefully.  I see that you have declared it daemon but your program should not depend on exactly how the Python interpreter shuts down.

Comment: BTW asyncio and tkinter work just fine together if you do it right, however, this will not solve your problem.  There is absolutely nothing wrong with calling event_generate from another thread - Tkinter can handle multiple threads, and there is no good reason to avoid it.  Your code looks fine to me, except for its lack of a graceful shutdown of the secondary thread.  It's hard to follow since you give it in small fragments.